# Can I use vim-like commands in the WIndows Command line in Windows 10?

Tags: vim, command-line, windows-10

Because I use vim (and obviously like it) while working in the command line, I often go through a few keystrokes before I realize I'm not in vim anymore. That's not a huge problem, but when entering a lot of commands on one line, vim-like navigation would really speed things up on the extremely rare occasion *cough* I make a typo. It would be great it there were a way to make command line typing act at least a little like vim (e.g. Normal mode, Insert mode, movement from the home keys, etc.)

I am open to using a different shell, but would prefer something I can use without learning a ton of new commands (e.g. command line or BASH like). I have else compiled many of my frequent command sequences into .bat files, which I would prefer not to have to change too much to get to work properly.

Comment: ["I'm not in vim anymore"](https://imgur.com/a/QwKSIRq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Windows, a good option would be to install [Git](https://git-scm.com/), which gives you "Git Bash", which is their distribution of [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/).

Now that you have bash, you can use `set -o vi` which puts your readline in Vim mode.

https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/vi-mode-in-bash/

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned [Clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/).  It works with `cmd.exe`, and has support for Vim (well, technically, Vi) key mappings.  Sadly, the documentation [seems unfinished](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/master/docs/clink.md) (to say the least); that said, I have found it to be quite stable, and have used it for a few years now.  Doing a quick search yields information on [how to set the default editing mode to Vi](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/135#issuecomment-35173699) (versus Emacs).

In short <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> switches to Vi mode (assuming one is currently in the default Emacs mode), and a standard [Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) [`inputrc`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9) in the right place (my file path is `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\clink\clink_inputrc`), with the right directive (`set editing-mode vi`) ensures that a new `cmd.exe` invocation starts off in Vi mode.

Answer (score 1):

> I am open to using a different shell, but would prefer something I can use without learning a ton of new commands (e.g. command line or BASH like)

In bash you can enter `vi-mode` with the command:

```
set -o vi
```

This will make shell-editing very similar to Vim-editing. For a cheat-sheet of vim-mode commands see: https://github.com/pkrumins/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/blob/master/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.txt